# Finding unique faces in a video

Tags: object-detection, facial-recognition, clustering

I am trying to find unique (distinct) faces in multiple videos files. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! What have you found so far? Please, edit your post to add more details. For example, faces of people or other animals? How do your datasets look like, etc?